# modify value of index in array on basis of another unique index in C#

Tags: c#, arrays

I am working with 2 object types array in C#, One of my array is populated from MS Access and other in being filled from MySql.

```
object[] Product = [{123, "Tea"},{234, "Coffee"},{345, "Drinks"}]; // from MySql

object[] ProductDetails = [{123, "T", 23.00},{234, "C", 25.02},{345, "D", 11.88}]; // from MS Access
```

I need to loop through its all `ProductDetails` to match with its ID in `Product` array , where ID matches it replace the name from `product` array to `productsdetails` array,

OR any other approach do it efficiently in c# code. **Records may be in thousands**.

Comment: Rather than two arrays, have you considered a `Dictionary`?

Comment: Provide compiling code and the code where you show what you have tried

Comment: Enumerate throught Ms Access and find match by ID in SQL. Just ensure you have indexes on ID column in SQL. If you want to work in-memory use Dictionary as said by @mjwills

Comment: you can convert the arrays to your own class or a `Dictionary` using `List<T>` , then you can use `.Find()` to test if your condition is true

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you see a good reason why you should not use multi-dimensional object arrays. Instead you should use a `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`. I'd suggest to implement a custom class `Product`. Then the dictionary would be a `Dictionary<int, Product>`. This would be very efficient and readable.

However, to answer your question and show the mess:

```
object[,] Product = { { 123, "Tea" }, { 234, "Coffee" }, { 345, "Drinks" } }; // from MySql
object[,] ProductDetails = { { 123, "T", 23.00 }, { 234, "C", 25.02 }, { 345, "D", 11.88 } };

for (int k = 0; k < ProductDetails.GetLength(0); k++)
{
    object id = ProductDetails[k, 0];
    string longName = null;
    bool idFound = false;
    for (int l = 0; l < Product.GetLength(0); l++)
    {
        if (id.Equals(Product[l, 0]))  // Equals necessary because boxing of int to object
        {
            idFound = true;
            longName = Product[l, 1] as string; 
            break;
        }
    }

    if (idFound)
    {
        ProductDetails[k, 1] = longName; 
    }
}
```

Comment: can you please re-write this in dictionary way

Comment: @user6594294: Sorry, no, i would have to show you a new class, the way i initialize the dictionary with sample objects and the code to access each elements. You can easily find tutorials for all of this. If you struggle somewhere you can ask another question

Answer (score 0):

If you're using linq you could just join the two arrays on the ID (I am unsure if you have to convert them to List() first), 
and then create a new array where you select want you want from each array.

```
var result = (from p in Products join pd in ProductDetails where p.Id equals pd.Id select new ...).ToList()
```

Comment: @Agent_Orange because?